# HTML report not showing messages from test teardown( fixture finalizer )

Tags: python, html, logging, pytest

HTML report for the test results( generated by pytest-html) doesnt contain the LOG messages from fixture finalizer.
    I try to use the pytest-html with pytest-catchlog to get the nice logical HTML TEST REPORT for example:

Example:

Testcase setup Log messages ( sent from Pytest Function Fixture )
Testcase steps Log messages ( sent from Test Function)
Testcase close Log messages ( sent from Pytest Function Fixture Finalizer )

The console/log file is OK/ shows all log messages.
In the HTML Report, I see the Log messages:
from Testcase setup,
from Testcase steps

but Testcase close/Fixture Finalizer Log messages are missing

I tried the @pytest.yield_fixture as well without success.
I will try to modify the html file with additional pytest hooks, as stated on plugin page...

packages: pytest-html, pytest-catchlog
platform: Python 2.7.13, pytest-3.0.7, py-1.4.33, pluggy-0.4.0
plugins: metadata-1.3.0, html-1.14.2, catchlog-1.2.2

Answer (score 1):

Pasting for the benefit of others who stumble upon this question. Pytest-html does not currently include logs from the teardown phase.

Somebody has recently developed a fix. At the time of writing this answer, the pull request is pending review.

https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-html/pull/271

Comment: It is helpful to show the code that pertains to the question to help others more efficiently and in a case where the link may no longer be valid, the answer still can be.

Comment: @nihiser thanks for the suggestion. However, the fix referenced in the link happens to involve several changes to a large script. I am not sure how to condense all that into a meaningful post involving some code. And I did not see a way of attaching a diff/file. Did you have something else in mind?

Comment: It appears to have been released in v3.0.0 and later - https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-html/commit/f2d41db1056a34af78822c2e45c525f7c1e7da67